# Distinct when local notification was tapped and when received

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I have app that send local notifications.
So I have two scenarios.

1. Application is in foreground, notification center is dragged out. Notification is recived. Notification center is being hidden.
2. Application is in foreground, notification center is dragged out. Notification is recived. Notification is selected.

My code to handel notifications

**AppDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification* notification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    //When App is launched from notification
    [self setupLocalNotification:notification.userInfo];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"USER INFO %@",notification.userInfo);
    [self setupLocalNotification:notification.userInfo];
}

-(void)setupLocalNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo {
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if ( state == UIApplicationStateInactive || state == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfo forKey:@"localNotification"];
        //This is for situation when I'm deep in navigation controller and this also trigger viewWillAppear in ViewController
        [[((MainPanelViewController*)[[self window] rootViewController]) startNC] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:false];
    } else {
        //something
    }
}
```

** MainPanelViewController**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //This is for situation when currently in ViewController
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(beacomeActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self checkLocalNotification];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (BOOL) checkLocalNotification{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"localNotification"];
    if (userInfo != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Notification");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowNotification" sender:self];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Problem**
I don't know how to distinct those two situations. Because every time notification is received when App is inactive then method `performSegueWithIdentifier` is being called.

Comment: is the above view controller code is of your MainPanelViewController??

Comment: Yes, sorry for misleading

Comment: When you pop to your MainPanelViewController , its viewDidAppear will be called and hence your checkLocalNotification method is called which  is performing the segue. If you want to perform segue when your app become active then handle this in your notifications that you have scheduled

Comment: Thank you for point out this matter.